# Changing the background color of UIImageView with circular image

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimageview

I'd like to change the background color of the space taken up by my UIImageView, which has a circular image, hence having white spaces around the view.
Below is a example of a rough idea of what I want to achieve, but I cant seem to do it, changing imageView.backgroundColor or imageView.tintColor doesn't seem to work.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb0U6.png)

These are snippet of my codes regarding the UIImageView

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: FUIImageView!
var prodImage: UIImage!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if prodImage != nil {
            self.imageView.image = prodImage
            self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            self.imageView.isCircular = true
            self.imageView.borderColor = UIColor.preferredFioriColor(forStyle: .positive)
            self.imageView.borderWidth = 1.0
        }
        else{
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://spotlight.dlme.clir.org/assets/default-52adc3dc03639885e8aa93763e29868269dd3b9dad4689f140c0175b4f945922.png")!))!
            self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            self.imageView.isCircular = true
            self.imageView.borderColor = UIColor.preferredFioriColor(forStyle: .negative)
            self.imageView.borderWidth = 1.0
        }


        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
    }
```

Comment: why can't you use a .png image and add background color to the image view. that will work out .

Comment: This method should work but the imageView's class is changes to some SAP ImageView Class that class prevent the background color to be appeared so you need to change this class to default UIImage class for getting your Idea to work properly.